# How can I write enums with inline calculation of the powers?

Tags: vb.net, math, enums

I have once seen a beautifully and easy to follow enum.

It was written in such a way that one didn't have to calculate the powers by himself (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, etc.), but instead, one could simply write like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.

The following is surely not correct, but you can get the flavor:

```
Public Enum eSomething 
        NotDefined = 0 ^ 2
        Max = 1 ^ 2
        Jeff = 2 ^ 2
        Lisa = 3 ^ 2
        Donald = 4 ^ 2
```

etc...

Does anybody know how to write it correctly?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It appears you have your base and exponent around the wrong way.

Comment: @tmighty - In my post I should have mentioned that to use integers I use Alt Drag to get rid of the L in 1L and delete everything after B31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
Public Enum eSomething
    NotDefined = CInt(2 ^ 0)
    Max = CInt(2 ^ 1)
    Jeff = CInt(2 ^ 2)
    Lisa = CInt(2 ^ 3)
    Donald = CInt(2 ^ 4)
End Enum
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for. Also, thanks for putting the changing value (0, 1, 2, 3) at the end for good readability.

Answer (score 0):

I have this enum that I find a convenient starting place...

```
<Flags()> Public Enum Bits As Long
    none = 0
    B00 = 1L << 0 ' 1
    B01 = 1L << 1 ' 2
    B02 = 1L << 2 ' 4
    B03 = 1L << 3 ' 8
    B04 = 1L << 4 ' 16
    B05 = 1L << 5 ' 32
    B06 = 1L << 6 ' 64
    B07 = 1L << 7 ' 128
    B08 = 1L << 8 ' 256
    B09 = 1L << 9 ' 512
    B10 = 1L << 10 ' 1,024
    B11 = 1L << 11 ' 2,048
    B12 = 1L << 12 ' 4,096
    B13 = 1L << 13 ' 8,192
    B14 = 1L << 14 ' 16,384
    B15 = 1L << 15 ' 32,768
    B16 = 1L << 16 ' 65,536
    B17 = 1L << 17 ' 131,072
    B18 = 1L << 18 ' 262,144
    B19 = 1L << 19 ' 524,288
    B20 = 1L << 20 ' 1,048,576
    B21 = 1L << 21 ' 2,097,152
    B22 = 1L << 22 ' 4,194,304
    B23 = 1L << 23 ' 8,388,608
    B24 = 1L << 24 ' 16,777,216
    B25 = 1L << 25 ' 33,554,432
    B26 = 1L << 26 ' 67,108,864
    B27 = 1L << 27 ' 134,217,728
    B28 = 1L << 28 ' 268,435,456
    B29 = 1L << 29 ' 536,870,912
    B30 = 1L << 30 ' 1,073,741,824
    B31 = 1L << 31 ' 2,147,483,648
    B32 = 1L << 32 ' 4,294,967,296
    B33 = 1L << 33 ' 8,589,934,592
    B34 = 1L << 34 ' 17,179,869,184
    B35 = 1L << 35 ' 34,359,738,368
    B36 = 1L << 36 ' 68,719,476,736
    B37 = 1L << 37 ' 137,438,953,472
    B38 = 1L << 38 ' 274,877,906,944
    B39 = 1L << 39 ' 549,755,813,888
    B40 = 1L << 40 ' 1,099,511,627,776
    B41 = 1L << 41 ' 2,199,023,255,552
    B42 = 1L << 42 ' 4,398,046,511,104
    B43 = 1L << 43 ' 8,796,093,022,208
    B44 = 1L << 44 ' 17,592,186,044,416
    B45 = 1L << 45 ' 35,184,372,088,832
    B46 = 1L << 46 ' 70,368,744,177,664
    B47 = 1L << 47 ' 140,737,488,355,328
    B48 = 1L << 48 ' 281,474,976,710,656
    B49 = 1L << 49 ' 562,949,953,421,312
    B50 = 1L << 50 ' 1,125,899,906,842,624
    B51 = 1L << 51 ' 2,251,799,813,685,248
    B52 = 1L << 52 ' 4,503,599,627,370,496
    B53 = 1L << 53 ' 9,007,199,254,740,992
    B54 = 1L << 54 ' 18,014,398,509,481,984
    B55 = 1L << 55 ' 36,028,797,018,963,968
    B56 = 1L << 56 ' 72,057,594,037,927,936
    B57 = 1L << 57 ' 144,115,188,075,855,872
    B58 = 1L << 58 ' 288,230,376,151,711,744
    B59 = 1L << 59 ' 576,460,752,303,423,488
    B60 = 1L << 60 ' 1,152,921,504,606,846,976
    B61 = 1L << 61 ' 2,305,843,009,213,693,952
    B62 = 1L << 62 ' 4,611,686,018,427,387,904
    B63 = 1L << 63 ' -9,223,372,036,854,775,808
End Enum
```